# Where Can I see a record of outbound emails?

Tags: email

I have an APEX script that generates emails after some event occurs. I would like to see a record of all the emails that have been sent. Is this possible in the Setup portion of SalesForce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access email logs, click Your Name | Setup | Monitoring | Email Log Files.

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/email_logs.htm

For that to work, the employee will need to have the "Modify All Data" as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a Compliance BCC email address, which will be added to the BCC of every email that is sent out of your org.  Of course, you'll get a lot more than just the emails generated by the apex script.  I have a separate inbox for this purpose.

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_compliancebcc.htm

Comment: Every day is a school day!